# PayPal IPN Sandbox response always INVALID

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to implement PayPals IPN on my website in asp.net using C#. I am using the sample code given by PayPal found here: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/GB/en_GB/files/developer/IPN_ASP_NET_C.txt

I have enabled IPN on my account with the URL of the ipn on my site.
The URL used in the code as you can see in the link above is the sandox url for paypal testing.

I am using the IPN Simulator and It's giving me "IPN sent successfully response" but on my website it displays invalid every time.

I have also tried displaying the strRequest string in a Label and all it shows me is "&cmd=_notify-validate" without quotes. I thought it was meant to add that part on to the rest of the returned data from PayPal.

Here is my button:

This is the button I'm using

```
<script src="paypal-button.min.js?merchant=myemail" 
                data-button="buynow" 
                data-name="name" 
                data-quantity="1" 
                data-amount="00.50" 
                data-currency="GBP" 
                data-shipping="0" 
                data-tax="0" 
                data-env="sandbox"
                data-return="http://site.net/thankyou.aspx"
                ></script>
```

What is going wrong?

UPDATE:

So.. to recap. 
I have 2 sandbox accounts. One business and the other personal. I enabled ipn on the business account. On my website I have the button shown above. The ipn page has the exact same code as the sample code given for the IPN in asp.net from paypal. I got the to website, click the buy now button and make the purchase using the personal account to the sandbox business account. The payment shows as complete and shows as sent with code 200 in the ipn history for the business account but when i check the label i entered on the ipn page it shows the word invalid.

Thanks!

Comment: Could tell me where you get the link, because it is missing other parameters? Normally, ***here is how PayPal Standard work*** - you redirect user to PayPal with other parameters. Then user proceeds the payment at PayPay site. Once the payment is success, PayPal redirects the user back your site.

Comment: I have a PayPal buy now button. When clicked you are taken to the PayPal site and the payment is made but the IPN returns to me INVALID.

Comment: What are the information/parameters you post to PayPal?

Comment: The code I have is exactly the same as the code in the link i posted. If I am correct, the string strRequest is the one being sent back to paypal. When I check this in a label it only shows "&cmd=_notify-validate". So I'm not sending back the correct information but I'm not sure what to do to fix it. :(

Comment: Just added the button im using also in the main post.

Comment: @Safinn Do you have realize that you use the sandbox version of it ? The sandbox version is not working with the real paypal informations that you have set

Comment: What do you mean real payment information? The button script has data-env="Sandbox" so it should use the sandbox right?

Comment: @Safinn yes is use the sandbox, so there you need to setup the sandbox  account to make it work

Comment: I have a sandbox business account and a sandbox personal account. I put the business accounts email in the button merchant section. Click the button and pay using the sandbox personal account but still not working :(

Comment: The payment goes through and shows as complete in the business account and in the IPN History it shows the transactions but they are all failed with code 404

Comment: I now have it so in IPN History the transactions are reported as sent with code 200 but on the IPN page on my site is still displays invalid...

Comment: You have posted this question three times – See my answer to your latest copy at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166097/invalid-paypal-ipn-response-however

Comment: Still not solved the problem. Anyone have any ideas?